# How to read maven settings with Java

Tags: java, maven

In my project, I want to get the settings content of Maven, for example, I want to reuse the proxy settings with maven.
Do you know how to get the settings XML? thank you

Comment: can you clarify a bit what do you need?

Comment: The `settings.xml` usually lies in the `.m2` directory in your home directory. You can read it and parse it, if you want.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve cause those informations are already used by Maven? It's not really clear what you are asking for and which kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Runtime.getRuntime()`  exec the command `mvn help:effective-settings` get the information?

Comment: but how to get the Maven path?